# Occasionally Getting 401 "Invalid Credentials" error when inserting to BigQuery table

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a node.js application that writes to a table in BigQuery. It works fine most of the time, but occasionally I get 401 "Invalid Credentials" error.

I am using the service account.

```
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

let bigQuery;
new BigQuery({ keyFilename: __dirname + '/big_query.json', projectId: config.google.project_id_prod });

const insertToBigQuery = (dataSet, table, object) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (config.releaseType === config.releaseTypeEnum.DEVELOPMENT || config.releaseType === config.releaseTypeEnum.STAGING) {
      logger.info(`Insert started to BigQuery. Dataset - ${dataSet} Table - ${table}`);
    }
    bigQuery.dataset(dataSet).table(table).insert(object, { ignoreUnknownValues: false })
      .then(() => {
        resolve({ insertedWithError: false });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        bigQuery.dataset(dataSet).table(table).insert(object, { ignoreUnknownValues: true })
          .then(() => {
            resolve({ insertedWithError: true, err: JSON.stringify(err) });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            reject(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
          });
      });
  });
};
```

> Most of the times this code works. Occasionally I get the 401 "Invalid Credentials" error

Comment: By any chance are any errors logged into any of the Stackdriver logs?

Comment: I see following error: {
  "code": 401,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Invalid Credentials",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "authError",
      "location": "Authorization",
      "locationType": "header"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. - Invalid Credentials"
}

Comment: Hows is this application being run?  Where are you running it from?  If you immediately re-run it, does it then work?  Are there any patterns on when it fails?  How are you authenticating with GCP?

Comment: It is run as a microservice inside Kubernetes. The behavior is intermittent

Comment: Have you setup authentication as described here ... https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

A loose thought strikes me ... do you have multiple pods hosting this service?  Is it replicated?  If yes, then is it possible that the reason for the non-deterministic behavior is that one of the pods is "sick" and when the load balancer picks that pod (non deterministically) that's when we see the issue?

Comment: I am positive that the authentication is setup correctly because this code works fine most of the times. We have only one POD hosting this service and it is not replicated. Is there a way to recover from this error in the code?